# How can i set proxy between jmeter and burp. as i want to sent all apies in burp target section from jmeter

Tags: jmeter, burp

How can I set a proxy between JMeter and burp? as I want to send all apies in burp target section from JMeter

Answer (score 0):

You can set Burp to use JMeter as the proxy:

[image]

So when you start JMeter [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) all the requests coming from Burp will be captured by JMeter and stored in form of [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

More information:

- [Burp Suite Options: Upstream Proxy Servers](https://portswigger.net/support/burp-suite-upstream-proxy-servers)
- [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter)

Comment: I want to send http requests which are captured on jmeter to burp...

Comment: I have created jmeter script for load testing (so all apis captured in jmeter ) now i want to send these api requests to burpsuite for security scan. so how i can set proxy so that when i run jmeter script all should be captured in burpsuite .. this is my actual requirment @dmitri

Comment: If you need the other direction you can configure JMeter to use Burp as the proxy like it's described in [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) article or using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request#Best%20Practices): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfbk3.png